# Reducing the number of 1's in a matrix based on some condition in matlab

Tags: matlab, networking, matrix

I have the following resultant matrix from one of the instances in a procedure which alters the size of the matrix dynamically.

```
result =

 1     1     0     0     1     0     0     0     1     0
 1     0     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
 0     1     1     1     1     0     1     1     1     1
 0     1     1     1     1     0     0     0     1     0
 1     1     1     1     0     1     1     1     1     1
 0     1     0     0     1     1     0     0     1     0
 0     1     1     0     1     0     1     0     1     0
 0     1     1     0     1     0     0     1     1     0
 1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     0     1
 0     1     1     0     1     0     0     0     1     1
```

The output for the following code looks like this

```
D1=sum(sum((result)))
D1 =

63
```

D1 specifying the total number of ones in the matrix, I need to reduce the total number of 1's to a maximum of 30% of D1 i.e. 63 ones has to become somewhere around 17-19 1's.

On doing so the following conditions have to be met.

1. None of the columns/rows should have all zeros or all ones.
2. If a row has all ones/zeros it can be removed and the final size of the      matrix should not be less than 20 percent of the initial matrix

Desperate request for help!

Thanks in advance.

**Edit: Percentage changed to 30**

Comment: What have you tried so far? Does the removal need to be random or can it go through the rows sequentially?

Comment: It would be nice if it does sequentially. - Skogsv

Comment: Deleting the row would be apt for my situation, however the size of reduction should be less than 20 percent of the initial matrix

Comment: Use `sum(result(:))` instead of `sum(sum...`

Comment: What about deleting columns?

Comment: Thanks and columns specify a particular parameter which is not allowed to be reduced

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is as follows:

1. Create a zero matrix of the same size as `result`
2. Generate random integers less than the total number of elements in your matrix
3. Use those integers as indices to assign a one into your new matrix
4. Check whether any rows have all ones in them, and then remove them if so

You haven't specified how to assign the ones in the new matrix, so I've just assumed a random assignment here.

```
function ReducedMatrix = ReduceMatrix(result)
    D1 = sum(result(:));
    NumberOfOnes = floor(D1*0.3);
    NewMatrix = zeros(size(result));
    NewMatrix(randi(numel(NewMatrix),1,NumberOfOnes)) = 1;
    ReducedMatrix = NewMatrix;
    while numel(ReducedMatrix)/numel(NewMatrix) > 0.2
        IndexOfFullRows = find(all(ReducedMatrix'));
        if isempty(IndexOfFullRows)
            break
        end
        ReducedMatrix(:,IndexOfFullRows(1)) = [];
    end
end
```

**Edit:** Removed column check based on comment and turned it into a function.

**Edit II:** Changed percentage of ones to keep to 30%.

Comment: Note that the OP _now_ wants ~30% ones, and **no** columns/rows that contain only zeros (rows can be deleted, but columns can't)...

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to comment on your answer, but maybe the OP should update the question with these new requirements? I could change my code to reflect the changes but as it stands I've answered the question..

Comment: You are absolutely right that this is the OP's responsibility. My answer also addresses the question, as-is :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution. The idea is to keep generating random matrices until one of them fits the criteria.

```
function out = q38888147(result)
if nargin < 1
  result = [
   1     1     0     0     1     0     0     0     1     0
   1     0     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
   0     1     1     1     1     0     1     1     1     1
   0     1     1     1     1     0     0     0     1     0
   1     1     1     1     0     1     1     1     1     1
   0     1     0     0     1     1     0     0     1     0
   0     1     1     0     1     0     1     0     1     0
   0     1     1     0     1     0     0     1     1     0
   1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     0     1
   0     1     1     0     1     0     0     0     1     1 ];
end

ones_ind = find(result);
n_ones = numel(ones_ind);
num_ones_to_keep = round(n_ones/10);

while true
  out = false(size(result)); % or tmp = zeros('like', result);
  % Sparsify:
  perm = randperm(n_ones, num_ones_to_keep);
  out(perm) = true;
  % Cleanup rows/columns:
  out = reduceInvalidRowCol(out);
  % Validate:
  if all(size(out) >= ceil(size(result)*0.2))
    break; % If all's good, finish
  end
end

end

function out = reduceInvalidRowCol(in,removeRows,removeCols)
if nargin < 3
  removeCols = false;
end
if nargin < 2
  removeRows = true;
end

out = in;
%% Check for all zeros / ones:
% Columns:
if removeCols
  s = sum(out,1);
  out(:,~s | s == size(out,1)) = [];
end
% Rows:
if removeRows
  s = sum(out,2);
  out(~s | s == size(out,2),:) = [];
end
end
```

Comment: The Solution works well, however i get columns with all zeros's, what do i do to get few more ones in those columns randomly

Comment: @CJs - Please don't change your problem after it was answered, this is not how Stack Overflow works. Of course you get columns with all-zeros, because the size of the input array is 10*10 and you only want 6 ones. You need to define better what's "few more ones". Note that if you add more ones then the ~10% will not be satisfied anymore... You have to decide what is more important to you.

Comment: Sorry about that, i am very new to stackoverflow as it can be clearly seen. ones more that 10% can be increased to 30%. Columns or rows without zeros are the top priority

Comment: What you need to do are two things: 1) increase `num_ones_to_keep` to ~30% by multiplying it by 3 (either before or after `round`); 2) inside the `% Validate:` condition, add a line that tests for all-zero columns based on the code I have near `removeCols` (and if such a case exists, simply don't `break`). This way a valid matrix will _eventually_ be generated.